# Is there a simple way to add a border to Kivy Buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`. Can someone tell me that how to add a different colour border to kivy button.

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (300, 100)


class User(Screen):
    pass


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.py

```
User:
    BoxLayout:

        Button:
            background_normal: ''
            text: 'Ok'
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suppose you mean *additionnaly* to the current background/border.

If so, you probably want to use some canvas instruction.

You probably want to add them in `canvas.before` so it's drawn *before* the text of the button.

The instruction you'll use will depend on the effect you want, but Line is probably a good start.

```
Button:
    text: 'test'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the border property of the Button Class,basically:
In kiv:

```
Button:
        border: (10,10,10,10)
```

I believe this will be the border image used by `BorderImage`

Disclaimer: Not tested but its along those lines

Answer (score 0):

you can use kivymd
in .py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (300, 100)

class User(Screen):
     pass

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
        Test().run()
```

and .kv

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
        background_normal: ''
        text: 'Ok'
```